# Why CSS dark grey is lighter then the original grey

Tags: css, colors

#### [JSBIN DEMO](http://jsbin.com/yewuy/2/edit)

[image]

Is this some kind of bug or they just made it wrong?

Shouldn't the dark gray be DARKER then the default grey?

#### HTML

```
<div class="lightgrey">Light Grey</div>
<div class="grey">Grey</div>
<div class="darkgrey">Dark Grey</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.lightgrey {background: lightgrey}
.grey {background: grey}
.darkgrey {background: darkgrey}
```

Comment: Not on my iPad, it isn't.

Comment: That's the answer I was looking for Mike ... guess I didn't searched enough. 1st time I vote my own question as duplicate.

Comment: They are kind of in a gray area.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

according to [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_colornames.asp) this seems to be correct.

- darkgray is #A9A9A9
- gray is #808080
- dimgray is #696969

Comment: The color "gray" is usually written with an 'a', not with an 'e', except for a string british accent :-) Though often both versions are handled alike.

Comment: It appears that '*grey' and '*gray' are handled the same, regardless of spelling